# Como establezco un registro por pagina en un dataTable (dataTable.js)

Tags: datatables

Quiero hacer lo siguiente: Obtengo unos registros en un dataSet desde sql server, los retorno al fromEnd sereializados en formato json, cuando los recibo en mi respuesta ajax lo convierto a formato json, ahora quiero pintarlos en un datatable paginado de la siguiente manera: si obtengo 4 registro sera un registro por cada pagina, entonces serán 4 paginas, un registro por pagina, no logro configurar el datatable para que quede de esa manera.... soy novato en el desarrollo web, necesito de su ayuda.

mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
<table id="tablaReportes" class="table table-hover">
    <thead id="tbl">
        <tr>
            <th>Fecha y Hora</th>
            <th>Limites alerta (inf/sup)</th>
            <th>Limites accion (inf/sup)</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Ver</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

cuando mi documento esta listo hago lo siguiente:

```
 $('#tablaReportes').DataTable({
    scrollY: 400,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: true,
    searching: false,
    ordering: false,
    info: false,
});
```

y la forma en la que recorro el el objeto json para agragar contenido a la tabla es la siguiente:

```
  $.each(json.Table, function (index, item) {

            var aLimites = [{ alertaIn: item.C019alertaIn },
                            { alertaSup: item.C019alertaSup },
                            { accionIn: item.C019accionIn },
                            { accionSup: item.C019accionSup },
                            { obsGrafica: item.C019obsGrafica }];

            $("#tablaReportes").append("<tr><td>" + item.C019fechaRegistro + " ; " + item.C019hora+ "</td>"
                + "<td>[" + item.C019alertaIn + "][" + item.C019alertaSup + "]</td>"
                + "<td>[" + item.C019accionIn + "][" + item.C019accionSup + "]</td>"
                + "<td>" + item.C019NomUsuario + "</td>"
                + "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='grafica(" + item.C019SeriesData + ", " + JSON.stringify(aLimites) + "," + item.C019codDetalle + ")'><i class='fa fa-line-chart'></i></button>&nbsp"
                + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='verObservacion(" + item.C019codDetalle + ")'><i class='fa fa-comments-o'></i></button></td></tr>");
        });
```

les agradecería bastante por su ayuda!

Comment: para establecer el numero de registros o records usa esto $('#example').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 50
} );

Comment: en ese caso es 50 pon lo que deseas

Comment: documentacion oficial https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength

Comment: No tengo resultados de esa manera, lo he intentado muchas veces de esa manera! :( ! ... muchas gracias igual !